# Round one corner rectangle - photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, cs6

What would be the best way to round one corner of a rectangle in photoshop CS6? I know how to do it in illustrator but am wondering if you would have merge and rasterise two shapes to get the one corner rounded look or if there  is a way it can stay vector? Or is it achieved through a mask?

Comment: Are you referring to vector shape layers or raster layers? How would you do it in Illustrator? It's probably fairly similar unless you use some effect or plug in.

Comment: Haven't used this in a long time, but I'm pretty sure 0 equals a sharp corner https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/corner-editor-photoshop-script/